create a bound generic function whilst preserving the generic nature and types
In typescript we can create a function that wraps another function, and still preserve all types of the wrapped function like this:
function boundCall<
    THeadParams extends unknown[],
    TTailParams extends unknown[], TReturn>(
        f: (...args: [...THeadParams, ...TTailParams]) => TReturn, ...boundHeadParams: THeadParams
    ) {
        return (...tailParams: TTailParams)=>{ return f(...boundHeadParams, ...tailParams)};
}

function noneGeneric(name: string, age: number, gender: "male" | "female") {
    console.log(name, age, gender);
    return gender;
}

const boundNoneGeneric = boundCall(noneGeneric, "classy");

const r1 = boundNoneGeneric(1 , "female"); 

which generates this d.ts file
declare function boundCall<THeadParams extends unknown[], TTailParams extends unknown[], TReturn>(f: (...args: [...THeadParams, ...TTailParams]) => TReturn, ...boundHeadParams: THeadParams): (...tailParams: TTailParams) => TReturn;
declare function noneGeneric(name: string, age: number, gender: "male" | "female"): "male" | "female";
declare const boundNoneGeneric: (age: number, gender: "male" | "female") => "male" | "female";
declare const r1: "male" | "female";

but as soon as we introduce generics to this mix we lose all types:
function genericTest<TLast>(name: string, age: number, gender: "male" | "female", last: TLast) {
    console.log(name, age, gender);
    return last;
}


const boundGeneric = boundCall(genericTest, "classy"); // type error here
const r2 = boundGeneric(1, "female", {test: true})

here is the .d.ts for this one
declare function boundCall<THeadParams extends unknown[], TTailParams extends unknown[], TReturn>(f: (...args: [...THeadParams, ...TTailParams]) => TReturn, ...boundHeadParams: THeadParams): (...tailParams: TTailParams) => TReturn;
declare function genericTest<TLast>(name: string, age: number, gender: "male" | "female", last: TLast): TLast;
declare const boundGeneric: (...tailParams: unknown[]) => unknown;
declare const r2: unknown;

I expected boundGeneric to preserve the types which should be a generic function itself:
type boundGeneric = <TLast>(age: number, gender: "male" | "female", last: TLast) => TLast

but I get:
declare const boundGeneric: (...tailParams: unknown[]) => unknown;

is there a way to preserve the types?
here is the full playground link: TS playground
thanks for your time wizards!

This is not currently possible; TS has some support higher order type inference from generic functions but there are lots of caveats to it, and it was implemented before variadic tuples existed. If you want to see this supported you might file a feature request for it. But for now the answer is "no". Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?
